# custom nemo actions / bash script

Tags: bash, cinnamon, file-manager, nemo

i am trying to add a custom action to the nemo file manager. The purpose of the action is just to replace all whitespace in the filename by "_".
My action file looks like this:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Normalize
Comment=replace all occurences of " " by "_"
Exec=<normalize.sh %F>
Selection=Any
Extensions=Any
```

The bash script normalize.sh is i the actions directory and looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" != 1 ]]
    then exit 1
fi

name=`echo "$1" | sed "s/\ /\_/g"`
mv "$1" "$name"

exit 0
```

Does anybody know, why this isn't working?

Comment: Where did you put script `normalize.sh` and is it have e`x`ecution flag?

Comment: normalize.sh is under $HOME/<user>/.local/share/nemo/actions (hence the <> around the script; the sample action file states, that if the script is in the same directory as the action you need <>); the scripts permissions are rwx--x--x

Comment: Try to use full path  `$HOME/<user>/.local/share/nemo/actions/normalize.sh`

Comment: No, that dosn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**

Your problem is <s>so trivial,</s> that `%F` is the filename, and the filename contains spaces, so you're calling the script by this way:

```
normalize.sh my fancy file
```

So `$1` becomes `my`, `$2` becomes `fancy` and `$3` becomes `file`. Now `$#` becomes 3.

---

**Fix 1 (recommended):**

To fix that. you don't need to check the number of arguments. Then you can use `$@` instead of `$1`. The script will look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

name=`echo "$@" | sed "s/\ /\_/g"`
mv "$@" "$name"

exit 0
```

---

**Fix 2:**

Another solution is to put quotes around `%F`. The correct code would be this:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Normalize
Comment=replace all occurences of " " by "_"
Exec=<normalize.sh "%F">
Selection=Any
Extensions=Any
```

---

**Improved script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mv "$@" "$(tr ' ' '_' <<< "$@")"
exit 0
```

- Normally `bash` is on `/bin/bash`. As yours seems to be on `/usr/bin/bash` (the first time that I see this) I put a <s>universal</s> workaround to run bash wherever it be. However you can see the path to bash typing `which bash` on a terminal.
- Removed conditional to count arguments.
- Why use `sed` for that existing `tr`?
- Instead of `echo` the file to `sed` or `tr`, better use `<<<`.
- Why not to put all in one line?

Comment: No, it still dosn't work.

Comment: Where yout put `normalize.sh`? Is it on path?

Comment: normalize.sh is at $HOME/<user>/.local/share/nemo/actions/normalize.sh; the sample actions file states, that <> are needed, when the file is in the actions directory; if also already tried using the absolute path

Comment: Ok, sorry. I thought that it was in PATH. Has `normalize.sh` execution permissions? And shebang? Did you try to put a line on the file like this `echo hooray > /home/johndoe/executed.txt`?

Comment: Yes, the permissions are rwx--x--x; yes the first line is "#!/usr/bin/bash"; i just tried and removed the check if the number of arguments is correct and inserted a command to open a terminal and it did, so at least the script gets executed, but still the file is not renamed

Comment: It seems the check for the right number of arguments caused the execution of the script to end prematurely; i corrected this by removing the check and i can confirm, that the script is now executed, but still the filename remains unchanged...

Comment: Please, add a line at the begin of the script like this: `zenity --info --text "$1 __ $2 __ $3 __ $4"`

Comment: The ouput is "$HOME/test/test __ test.d __  __  ; that means for some reason he splits the file name into two seperate arguments; thank you for this clue - i will rewriter the script

Comment: Try now, I edited the answer.

Comment: I edited again to explain it better. I'm working on the answer.

Comment: Edited! Now is so near to perfection (that is what I think)!

Comment: Yes, this answer is now very good indeed, thanks! Also: Zenity seems to be interesting and useful; i didn't know about that.

Comment: Off-topic: You can learn the life and miracles of zenity with `man zenity`. It's very useful.

Comment: '$@' should not work. instead "$@" might work.

Comment: Thanks, @AlainPannetier! Fixed! ‍♂️